# Login programmatically with Django-AllAuth?

Tags: django, testing, django-allauth

Is there a simple way to programmatically login with AllAuth? I don't really care about cookies or sessions, I just want to get a `Client` that corresponds to an AllAuth user account.

Example:

```
from django.test import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.first()  # assuming user registered with AllAuth
client.login(username=user.username)  # password needed!
```

AllAuth user accounts are not guaranteed to have passwords so the code above won't work. So how can I get the client to login without a password to make testing easier?

Comment: Would using [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APITestCase's` method `force_authenticate`

```
class Test(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = ... #get the user
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
```

Here is the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication)